# Finding out what went wrong with the Windows 2008 R2 Production server

Tags: webserver, windows-server-2008-r2

This morning my Production server (Windows 2008 R2) went offline for 10 mins and also RDP connection was lost for the given duration. During this period the IIS 7 hosted production web site also stopped responding. 

Luckily though, after the 10 mins the server was up by its own and RDP session was restored to previous state. 

Now the question is how do I find out what went wrong in the server and is there any logs which I can go through verify my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you goto the run prompt and type `eventvwr` it will open Event Viewer. From within here expand the `Windows Logs` tree and look through the `System` logs. Something will have caused the reboot and you should be able to find it through here.

A good old chesnut is Windows Updates. They aren't on auto install and reboot are they? :]